# track error dialogs using omniture app measurement

Tags: android, adobe-analytics

I am not familiar with omniture tracking, so hoping that someone who has worked on that would be able to help. What I want is to track the number of times an error dialog is displayed. For example if my app shows time out error dialog, it should be tracked in site catalyst.. Can anyone tell, how can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out SiteCatalyst's [Android AppMeasurement User Guide](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/android/index.html) for general details on implementation methods.

To track error messages, you will want to create a custom variable (a prop or eVar) and dedicate it to error messages. Then, whenever an error message is fired, define that variable and send an image request. It'd probably be a good idea to define other variables at the same time (such as the current page) so you can get additional dimensions on when/how they're firing.

The [pageType](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/index.html#pageType) variable is usually used for error handling in JavaScript tracking libraries, however this has been [removed in recent Android libraries.](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/android/index.html#Android_Version_2x_to_3x_Migration_Guide)